# Which homotopy 2-types are H-spaces?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $X$ be a connected CW-complex with $\pi_k(X)$ trivial for $k >2$. Is it known under which circumstances $X$ is an $H$-group?

I have been able only to deduce the necessary condition that $\pi_1(X)$ has to be abelian and act trivially on $\pi_2(X)$. Furthermore, if the necessary condition holds, vanishing of the Postnikov invariant $\beta \in H^3( \pi_1(X), \pi_2(X))$ is a sufficient condition. Thus the interesting case is that of $\beta$ nonzero.

Comment: A slightly stronger and more natural condition (I don't know if it's equivalent to being an $H$-group in this case) is that $X$ has a delooping $BX$; this means not only that $\pi_1$ is abelian and acts trivially on $\pi_2$ but that the Postnikov invariant must arise from a Postnikov invariant in $H^4(B^2 \pi_1, \pi_2)$. This is exactly the space of quadratic maps $\pi_1 \to \pi_2$, although I don't know how to describe the map to $H^3(B \pi_1, \pi_2)$ in these terms.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan If $X$ has a delooping $BX$, then $X$ admits a grouplike $A_\infty$ structure, which is much stronger than being an $H$-space, right?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I think that the map to $H^3(B \pi_1, \pi_2)$ is always zero. The $H^4(B^2\pi_1, \pi_2)$ classes correspond to certain braided monoidal categories, and I am pretty sure these can be realized with trivial associators - so the map should be zero.

Comment: Chris, but not always with a symmetric braiding.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The necessary condition is a "additivity"-type condition on the $k$-invariant.

Suppose $\pi_1 X = G$ and $\pi_2 X = A$. As you correctly point out, $G$ must be abelian and act trivially on $A$. Under these circumstances, the $k$-invariant is expressible as a natural map of pointed spaces
$$
\beta: K(G,1) \to K(A,3).
$$
(Normally $\beta$ can only be constructed as a map $K(G,1) \to K(A_G, 3)$ in terms of the coinvariants.) The space $X$ is the homotopy fiber of $\beta$, and the $k$-invariant of $X \times X$ is $\beta \times \beta$.

This means that, in order to get an $H$-space, it is necessary and sufficient to get a homotopy commutative diagram of pointed spaces:
$\require{AMScd}$
$$
\begin{CD}
K(G,1) \times K(G,1) @>m>> K(G,1)\\
@V \beta \times \beta V V @VV \beta V\\
K(A,3) \times K(A,3) @>>m> K(A,3)
\end{CD}
$$
Here $m$ is the $H$-space multiplication on Eilenberg--Mac Lane spaces for abelian groups, which induces addition on cohomology. In terms of the projection maps $p_i: K(G,1) \times K(G,1) \to K(G,1)$, homotopy commutativity of this diagram says that
$$
m^*(\beta) = p_1^*(\beta) + p_2^*(\beta).
$$

If there is a sufficiently good Kunneth formula (e.g. if $A$ is a ring and $H_*(K(G,1);A)$ are finitely generated projective) then $m^*$ is a "coproduct"
$$
m^*: H^*(K(G,1); A) \to H^*(K(G,1); A) \otimes_A H^*(K(G,1); A)
$$
and under this identification we are asking that $\beta$ is primitive: $m^*(\beta) = \beta \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes \beta$.

If we think of $\beta$ as representing a cohomology operation $H^1(-;G) \to H^3(-;A)$, this condition equivalently asks that $\beta$ is additive: $\beta(x + y) = \beta(x) + \beta(y)$.

Comment: Are there non-zero beta which satisfy this condition?

Comment: @ChrisSchommer-Pries That I don't know. As you noted above, the most natural source of additive cohomology operations does not give any. If $G$ is free then there are also no such cohomology operations.

Comment: Using a free resolution $0 \to R \to F \to G \to 0$ to get a fiber sequence $K(F,1) \to K(G,1) \to K(R,2)$ we can use the Serre spectral sequence. There are two potential nonzero contributions to $H^3$, but the first is from $H^3(K(F,1);A)$ and we already said that has no primitives. That reduces to checking if there are any primitive elements in the cokernel of
$$
H^2(K(F,1); A) \to H^2(K(R,2); H^1(K(F,1); A))
$$
which is isomorphic to a map
$$
Hom(\Lambda^2 F, A) \to Hom(R \otimes F, A).
$$
This is about where I ran out of steam...

Comment: I think there are none. Split A and G into cyclic summands. If beta is a natural group homomorphism, so are the operations obtained by including summands into G and projecting to summands in A. If beta is nonzero *one of these* is nonzero. So we can reduce to the case that G and A are both cyclic of prime or infinite order, where one can explicitly compute all cohomology operations and see that the only additive one is zero. Have I made an error here?

Comment: @mme "If beta is nonzero [then] one of these is non-zero". Is that correct? I think that is right for the A's, but for the G's aren't there "cross terms"? For example if A=R is a ring and G = R x R xR, there is an operation corresponding to 3-fold cup product. Its restriction to any one factor of R of G will be zero. However that beta is not additive, so maybe this is okay for the additive betas?

Comment: @Chris I'm just making a linear algebra claim: if $\bigoplus_i G_i \to \bigoplus_j A_j$ is linear, then it can be computed as the action of a matrix of homomorphisms $G_i \to A_j$, and I think this is just the claim that finite direct sums are biproducts. If all of these terms are zero, then so is their direct sum. So additivity is crucial. (I have now used the terms "additive", "group homomorphism", and "linear" synonymously, which might add to confusion.)

Comment: @mme If the groups involved (even just G) are finitely generated, yes, absolutely; a direct sum decomposition gives you a matrix decomposition of the primitives, and you can reduce to the case where G is cyclic. I'm worried (perhaps needlessly?) about eg the possibility of lim^i terms if G is not finitely generated.

Comment: A non-zero $\beta$ is the non-trivial element of $H^3(K(\mathbb{Z}/2,1), \mathbb{Z}/4)\cong \mathbb{Z}/2$. The corresponding 2-type is the loop space of the Postnikov piece with $k$-invariant the generator of $H^4(K(\mathbb{Z}/2,2), \mathbb{Z}/4)\cong \mathbb{Z}/4$.

Answer (score 5):

I just wanted to add to Tyler Lawson's answer that all the maps $\beta\colon K(G,1)\rightarrow K(A,3)$ ($G$ and $A$ abelian and no action of $G$ on $A$) satisfying his additivity condition are loop maps by Stasheff's Homotopy Associativity of $H$-Spaces II (Theorem 5.3). Hence for 2-types being an $H$-space is the same as being a loop space. See also Qiaochu Yuan's comment.

In terms of $k$-invariants, the condition is that the $k$-invariant of the 2-type is in the image of the so-called cohomology 'suspension' morphism

$$H^4(K(G,2),A)\longrightarrow H^3(K(G,1),A),$$

which is induced by taking loops on the corresponding sets of homotopy classes of maps between Eilenberg-MacLane spaces.

The source is very well understood, it coincides with
$$\hom(\Gamma(G),A).$$
Here $\Gamma(G)$ is the target of the universal quadratic map $G\rightarrow\Gamma(G)$. Recall that a map $\gamma\colon G\to B$ between abelian groups is *quadratic* if $G\times G\to B\colon (x,y)\mapsto\gamma(x+y)-\gamma(x)-\gamma(y)$ is bilinear.

An example with non-trivial $k$-invariant can be constructed as follows. It suffices to show that

$$H^4(K(\mathbb{Z}/2,2),\mathbb{Z}/4)\longrightarrow H^3(K(\mathbb{Z}/2,1),\mathbb{Z}/4)$$

coincides with

$$\mathbb{Z}/4\twoheadrightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2.$$

Indeed, $H^3(K(\mathbb{Z}/2,1),\mathbb{Z}/4)$ is well-known to be the elements annihilated by $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}/4$, which identifies with $\mathbb{Z}/2$. A normalised $3$-cocycle representing the generator is
$$f\colon \mathbb{Z}/2\times \mathbb{Z}/2\times \mathbb{Z}/2\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}/4,\qquad f(1,1,1)=2.$$
(I will omit notations for classes in quotients of $\mathbb{Z}$ since the meaning in each case will be clear from the context.)

The universal quadratic map for $\mathbb{Z}/2$ is $\gamma\colon \mathbb{Z}/2\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/4$, $\gamma(0)=0$, $\gamma(1)=1$. Hence $\Gamma(\mathbb{Z}/2)=\mathbb{Z}/4$ and
$$\hom(\Gamma(\mathbb{Z}/2),\mathbb{Z}/4)=\hom(\mathbb{Z}/4,\mathbb{Z}/4)=\mathbb{Z}/4.$$

In order to compute the suspension morphisms I'm going to use crossed modules and their semi-stable version called reduced quadratic modules by Baues (see his book on 4-dimensional complexes). It is well known that 3-dimensional group cohomology classifies crossed modules (Eilenberg-MacLane or one of them alone, I don't currently remember). Similarly $\hom(\Gamma(\mathbb{Z}/2),\mathbb{Z}/4)$ classifies reduced quadratic modules. The generator is represented by the reduced quadratic module
$$\mathbb{Z}\otimes \mathbb{Z} \stackrel{\langle-,-\rangle}\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}/4\stackrel{\partial}\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}$$
where $\partial(a,b)=2a$ and $\langle x,y\rangle =(0,{xy}).$ This is because $\ker \partial=\mathbb{Z}/4$, $\operatorname{coker}\partial=\mathbb{Z}/2$ and the map $\mathbb{Z}/2\mapsto \mathbb{Z}/4$ defined by ${x}\mapsto{\langle x,x\rangle}$ coincides with the aforementioned universal quadratic map. The loop crossed module of this reduced quadratic module is
$$\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}/4\stackrel{\partial}\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z},$$
where the source is equipped with an exponential action of the target defined by
$$x^a=x+\langle\partial(x),a\rangle.$$
(Crossed modules usually consist of non-abelian groups and reduced quadratic modules too, but in this case everything is abelian because they are very small, this simplifies a lot the computations). A 3-cocycle
$$g\colon \mathbb{Z}/2\times \mathbb{Z}/2\times \mathbb{Z}/2\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}/4$$
representing the cohomology class of this crossed module is defined by the following choices:

We first need a set-theoretic splitting of $\partial$, that we define as
$$s\colon \mathbb{Z}/2\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z},\qquad s(0)=0,\quad s(1)=1.$$
Now, for each pair of elements $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}/2$ we need $t(x,y)\in \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}/4$ such that
$$\partial(t(x,y))=-s(y)-s(x)+s(x+y).$$
This measures the failure of $s$ to be a morphism.
We take $t(0,-)=(0,0)$, $t(-,0)=(0,0)$, and $t(1,1)=(1,0)$.
With these choices $g$ is
$$g(x,y,z)=t(x,y)^{s(z)}+t(x+y,z)-t(x,y+z)-t(y,z)\in\ker\partial=\mathbb{Z}/4.$$
Different choices produce cohomologous cocycles.
This cocycle is normalised because $t(0,-)$ and $t(-,0)$ vanish, so we only have to compute
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
g(1,1,1)&=&t(1,1)^{s(1)}+t(1+1,1)-t(1,1+1)-t(1,1)\\
&=&t(1,1)+\langle \partial t(1,1), s(1)\rangle +t(0,1)-t(1,0)-t(1,1)\\
&=&\langle \partial t(1,1), s(1)\rangle\\
&=&\langle \partial (1,0), 1\rangle\\
&=&\langle 2, 1\rangle\\
&=&(0,2).
\end{array}$$
The second coordinate (the kernel of $\partial$) is $2\in \mathbb{Z}/4$, therefore, $g=f$ above. This concludes the proof of the claim.